# How show that text as a table

Tags: php, html, tabular

How I can show that as a table?

I mean how I can show that "Director:" and results in a table?

```
echo '<strong>IMDb ID: </strong><a class="movie" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt'.$results['imdbid'].'" target="_blank">';
echo ''.$results['imdbid'].'</a><br>';
echo '<strong>Director: </strong>'.$results['director'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>Cast: </strong>'.$results['lead'].', '.$results['cast'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>Genre: </strong>'.$results['genre'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>Country: </strong>'.$results['country'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>Runtime: </strong>'.$results['runtime'].' min.<br>';
echo '<strong>Medium: </strong>'.$results['disctype'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>IMDb Rating: </strong>'.$results['imdbrating'].'.<br>';
echo '<strong>Rating: </strong>'.$results['personalrating'].'.<br><br>';
echo '<strong>Synopsis:<br></strong>'.$results['synopsis'].'<br>';
echo '</div><br>';
```

Comment: Your question is too vague

Comment: Change the HTML to use a table.

Comment: add `<table>` and the rest of the html markup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean something like this? Only thing I could think of you could have meant by your absolutely and extreme vage question...

```
<?php
echo '<table border="1px">';
echo '<tr><td><strong>IMDb ID: </strong></td><td><a class="movie" href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt'.$results['imdbid'].'" target="_blank"><td></tr>';
echo '<tr>'.$results['imdbid'].'</a></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Director: </strong></td><td>'.$results['director'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Cast: </strong></td><td>'.$results['lead'].', '.$results['cast'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Genre: </strong></td><td>'.$results['genre'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Country: </strong></td><td>'.$results['country'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Runtime: </strong></td><td>'.$results['runtime'].' min.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Medium: </strong></td><td>'.$results['disctype'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>IMDb Rating: </strong></td><td>'.$results['imdbrating'].'.</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Rating: </strong></td><td>'.$results['personalrating'].'.<br></td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td><strong>Synopsis:</strong></td><td>'.$results['synopsis'].' </td></tr>';
echo '</table>';
?>
```